# A library quesion regarding externs

Tags: c, libraries

This is regarding user code and user constructed libraries. If there is some global declaration:

```
bar_t fu;
```

Can `fu` possibly be accessed by a library? Note, I'm not concerned with normal programming practices, rather I'm concerned with the mere possibility.

Answer (score 1):

If `bar_t fu;` appears outside of any function, then `fu` has external linkage.

Per the C standard, any other translation unit, including one in a library, can declare `extern bar_t fu;` to link to it, and then they can access the object named `fu` by using its name.

Linkers often have ways to strip names from object modules, so it may be possible to build the program in such a way that the library cannot link to the `fu` name, in spite of the C standard.

Of course, a library can also access an object if the address of the object is given to the library, or if the library abuses its access to memory to access things it should not.